Creating a trigger that throws error if any contain email is used in lead record. Getting iisues in code
public class LeadTriggerHandler {
    public static void CheckEmailExistinLead(list<Lead>ListofLead)
    {
        map<string,contact>ListOfMapRecords=new map<string,contact>();
        list<contact>ListofContactRecords=[SELECT id,email FROM Contact ];
        for(contact con:ListofContactRecords)
        {
            ListOfMapRecords.put(con.email,con);
        }
        for(Lead lee:trigger.new)
        {
            if(lee.Email!=null)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }

}



Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], and take our quick [tour]. We would ask that you [edit] your question to include the error message as text, rather than just a screenshot, because this makes it less accessible for users that depend on accessibility features to access our content (e.g. screen readers).

In an Apex class, the Trigger variables are always a generic sObject, rather than a specific type, because the compiler does not know how you intend to use this code. Instead, you should iterate over ListofLead, which is presumably Trigger.new that you'd pass in as the parameter to this method.
Further, you must not query the entire database to find matching emails. This will run up against governor limits very quickly. Instead, you should first aggregate the values to use, then query only those records that match, and then perform any action you wish to take.
Here's a modified version to get you started.
public static void CheckEmailExistinLead(list<Lead>ListofLead) {
  Map<String, Contact> contactsByEmail = new Map<String, Contact>();
  // Aggregate values you want to query for
  for(Lead leadRecord: ListofLead) {
    contactsByEmail.put(leadRecord.Email, null);
  }
  // Ignore leads with no email
  contactsByEmail.remove(null);
  // Query for matching contacts
  for(Contact contactRecord: [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :contactsByEmail.keySet()]) {
    contactsByEmai.put(contactRecord.Email, contactRecord);
  }
  // Check to see if any leads match a contact by email
  for(Lead leadRecord: ListofLead) {
    Contact contactRecord = contactsByEmail.get(leadRecord.Email);
    if(contactRecord != null) {
      // do something here
    }
  }
}


Working thanks a lot
